# How to create and zip a docker container for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create and then zip a Docker container to upload to S3 to be run by an AWS Lambda function. I was trying to work off an article but the instructions are sparse (https://github.com/abhisuri97/auto-alt-text-lambda-api).

I've installed Docker and the Amazon Linux image but I don't know how to create a Docker container that contains the github repo, and then zip it so that it can be accessed by Lambda.

This is what I've tried to piece together from other tutorials:

```
git clone https://github.com/abhisuri97/auto-alt-text-lambda-api.git

cd auto-alt-text-lambda-api

docker run -v -it amazonlinux:2017.12

zip -r -9 -q ~/main.zip
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions aren't clear but I suspect the reference to Docker is just for testing. You don't need Docker to run an AWS Lambda function. You will need an AWS API Gateway API though to execute the Lambda function over HTTPS.

I'd recommend starting with a CloudFormation stack using the AWS Serverless Application Mode (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html).

Create an S3 bucket for the zip file and create a CloudFormation template similar to:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: application.predict
      Runtime: python2.7
      Events:
        HttpGet:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: 'auto-alt-text-api'
            Method: get
```

Package the Lambda function with:

`aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --output-template-file template-out.yaml --s3-bucket <your-bucket> --s3-prefix <your-prefix>`

Then deploy it with:

`aws cloudformation deploy --template-file template-out.yaml --stack-name auto-alt-text-lambda-api-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

You will probably have to add IAM roles and Lambda permissions to the template for the application to work properly.

Comment: Hi @Rik, thanks so much for answering. I had a couple of quick questions, after I've packaged the Lambda function and deployed it, do I then upload the zipped github repo to my S3 bucket? And would the S3 prefix be auto-alt-text-lambda-api/ if the zip file is auto-alt-text-lambda-api.zip?

Comment: If you run the `aws cloudformation package ...` command from the top level of the repo it will zip it up and put it in the S3 bucket with the prefix you specify (it can be anything).

Comment: Awesome, got it to package and deploy. Had to include the template.yaml file in the github repo or else it threw an error about the CodeUri field. I'll update the question a little later once I've figured out how to add a CloudWatch event and API Gateway and include how to do those bits. Thanks @Rik!